# How to detect availability of GUI in Bash/Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, user-interface

I'm writing a CLI in NodeJS. As I can easily run bash/shell commands using the child_process, I'd like to know the easiest **most cross platform way** to detect GUI availability in bash/shell.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're writing a CLI, why do you need GUI availability?

Comment: Because I want to launch an alternative electron app if GUI is available, it's fency :D

Comment: Probably checking for existence of the environment variable DISPLAY is the best bet. Not sure it's 100% reliable check on MacOS, though.

Comment: Indeed, the DISPLAY variable does not exist on OSX :/

Comment: Isn't Linux the only platform you have to worry about, as most people don't ssh into computers running the other platforms?

Comment: Just launch your app. If there is a GUI, it will run. If not, it will fail in a predictable way. If you detect that predictable way, move into CLI operation - otherwise fail in error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On macOS, there's not a clearly appropriate way to check this from a shell, as such. There's a programmatic way, and we can use an interpreted language to take advantage of that.

Here's a little script that outputs one of three states, Mac GUI, Mac non-GUI, or X11:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_macos_gui() {
  command -v swift >/dev/null && swift <(cat <<"EOF"
import Security
var attrs = SessionAttributeBits(rawValue:0)
let result = SessionGetInfo(callerSecuritySession, nil, &attrs)
exit((result == 0 && attrs.contains(.sessionHasGraphicAccess)) ? 0 : 1)
EOF
)
}

if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
  if check_macos_gui; then
    echo "Mac GUI session"
  elif [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    echo "Mac X11 GUI session"
  else
    echo "Mac non-GUI session"
  fi
elif [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  echo "X11 GUI session"
fi
```

Macs can have an X server installed, in which case `DISPLAY` is defined. However, I don't know if your Electron app will work properly in that configuration. So, I detected it separately.

Comment: Why `swift <(cat <<"EOF"` instead of `swift - <<"EOF"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If it receives its input from stdin rather than a filename argument, it behaves as though it's interactive and exits with 0 status regardless of what's passed to `exit()`. Also, it produces annoying extraneous output.

Comment: I wonder if we have different releases. `swift - <<<'import Security; exit(3)'; echo $?` emits no output at all (prior to the `echo`) and shows exit status 3 for me -- that's with *Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)*

Comment: ...or perhaps the behavior you mention above is *without* the explicit `-` specifying stdin?

Comment: Yeah, the explicit `-` seems to make the difference. For the record, I'm currently testing on Sierra with Xcode 8, so: *Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.51 clang-802.0.41)*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
if [ x$DISPLAY != x ] ; then
  echo "GUI Enabled"

else
  echo "GUI Disabled"

fi
```

All this does is checks the `$DISPLAY` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Or this :
`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`

Comment: Both of these are useful, but Linux only. A typical macOS session will have neither of these environment variables set.

Comment: This is helpful on linux (which is what I was looking for). See https://superuser.com/a/1643180/283518 for more info. Also FWIW, a little testing ssh'ing to a raspberry pi shows that `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` did not exist in that session (nor did the other 2)

Answer (score 0):

Check if DISPLAY is set in the environment.  If it is, you have an Xserver running.  If not, you don't.  Pretty sure that wayland sets it too.

Comment: He tagged it as MacOS as well. Not sure DISPLAY will be set unless Xquartz is installed.

Comment: I missed that.  I'm not sure, either.